# MySQL Check if table exists error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to check if a table already exists, however I can't get this working.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM sysobjects 
    WHERE xtype='u' AND name='tablename') 
        SELECT 'table already exists.' 
ELSE 
BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE Week_(
             id INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY (id),
             ...
             ...)
             END;
```

My error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='u' AND name' at
>   line 1

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sysobjects, xtype='u'? Looks like you are using MS Sql Server.

Comment: aha, so that's why it didn't work ;) I'm using MySQL, found this code somewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In MySQL you can use the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DBName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
```

**OR**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'TableName'
```

Comment: Note: the Select from information_schema.TABLES does not work in very early version of MySQL (e.g 4.1) as they didn't have those tables