# Idiorm (MySQL) - Raw query - SHOW TABLES LIKE

Tags: mysql, orm, idiorm

I use [Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm) as ORM for MySQL with PHP.

I need to check if a table is created or not.

**In SQL**

This works in phpMyAdmin

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'ro_globals'
```

**What I tried in Idiorm**

```
ORM::raw_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'ro_globals'")->count()
```

> Call to undefined method admin::count()

Is it possible to make this work with Idiorm? If so, how?

Comment: So what kind of object is actually returned by `raw_query`?

Comment: Their own example for raw_query: $people = ORM::for_table('person')->raw_query('SELECT p.* FROM person p JOIN role r ON p.role_id = r.id WHERE r.name = :role', array('role' => 'janitor'))->find_many(); It seems like it's only to be used with the for_table.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799559/mysql-check-if-table-exists-error/13799591#13799591

Comment: Maybe I got something in my eyes, but `find_many` is another method than `count`, right? Check, which type of object you are getting back from `raw_query`: `var_dump( get_class( ORM::raw_query( '…' ) ) );` to know which methods it provides. Just trying out random method names wouldn't lead to success. Also `SELECT` queries do return data in a different format than `SHOW` queries.

Comment: @JensTörnell You are right `raw_query()` is not to be used in this way, but with `for_table`. Recently there was some code added to the `develop` branch of Idiorm to support this style with a method called `raw_execute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in a comment by Saharsh. It's not a Idiorm problem, it could be solved with SQL.

**Result**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct anwser is:

```
ORM::forTable()->rawQuery('SHOW TABLES')->findMany()->count();
```

or with underscore:

```
ORM::for_table()->raw_query('SHOW TABLES')->find_many()->count();
```

Prefixed tables:

```
ORM::for_table()->raw_query('SHOW TABLES LIKE ' . $prefix . '%')->find_many()->count();
```